# The differential $d$ is a $k$-linear derivation

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $R$ be a local ring with maximal ideal $m$ and residue field $k$ satisfying the tangent space conditions:

1. There is an inclusion $k \subset R$ that gives a splitting of the natural map $R \longrightarrow k$.
2. The ideal $m$ is finitely generated.

Under these conditions, $R/m^2$ splits canonically as $k \oplus T^*_x$, where the cotangent space $T^*_x$ is defined as $T^*_x = m/m^2$.

Given $f \in R$, we define its *differential* $df$ as the projection of $(f \ \text{mod} \ m^2)$ to $T^*_x$ under the above decomposition.

I'm trying to prove the following lemma (which is left as an exercise in the book):

> **Lemma** $d : R \longrightarrow T_R^*$ is a $k$-linear derivation, i.e., it satisfies the Leibinz rule $d(fg) = f(x) dg + g(x) df$.

I was given the idea that under these conditions, $R$ is a graded ring and I could write an element $a \in R$ as $a = k_a + u + \mathcal{O}(2)$, where $k_a \in k$ and $u \in m$. But if I follow this lead, then I get that $d(ab) = k_a d(b) + k_b d(a)$, and I'm not sure if it makes any sense.

Comment: Can't you check $k_a d(b)=a(x)d(b)$, by definition of $k_a$?

Comment: When I compute $ad(b)$ I get $a d(b) = (k_a + u + \mathcal{O}(2)) v = k_a v + \mathcal{O}(2)$. Then, $d(ab) = a d(b) + b d(a) \text{ mod m}^2$. It's not too strange actually, since $T^*_x = m/m^2$. I'm just not sure if it's correct.

Comment: Order 2 or more elements play no role in your computations and so can safely ignore them.